# What do you call a short fence made of metal inside a garden used to protect flowers?

Tags: word-request

[image: w]

What do you call a short fence made of metal inside a garden used to protect flowers? Is there a specific word for it, or is it just called a short iron fence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In North America, **edging** (or sometimes **landscape edging**) is something that divides different landscaping features from each other - for example, dividing a flower garden from a lawn.

If you want to specify that this edging takes the form of a fence (as opposed to inlaid bricks or stones), it's usually called a **garden fence** or a **garden edging fence**.

Answer (score 0):

These fences are sold under two names:

**Hoop top fencing panels**

&

**Bow top fencing panels**

Googling these names will bring up relevant images.

https://fencingsuperstore.co.uk/ranges/bowtop-railings